# Unable to Load assembly>>System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core,

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

Need some exact reason.

> formatSystem.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'System.Core,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' at
>   Crypto.StringCipher.Encrypt(String clearText) at
>   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set
>   the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD)
>   to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly
>   bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry
>   value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

This is happening when I try to encrypt data with a assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems `Crypto` is compiled with Framework 3.5

Just check if `.Net Framework Version 3.5` is available on the machine.